Is this a real early draft of the script for The Matrix?
Browsing some questions on this site, I stumbled upon an early draft of The Matrix. Here is the link: http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/matrix_96_draft.txt
I remember reading similar scripts in the past - I even read a draft for Reloaded back in the day where Agent Smith had a ponytail!
Are these scripts real? Or just fan-made?

What makes you think they are not genuine? Films go through a tremendous amount of hurdles, including rewrites, sometimes over many years and through different hands, before someone calls 'action!', and even then it isn't over as many films have rewrites whilst filming, and even then have reshoots after the main film has been already shot.

Because I find hard to believe that the wachowskis or anyone at wb would post any draft or script online. What evidence do you have that those are genuine?

Are you saying that the wachowskis vowed to never ever let an early draft be seen?

@blobbymcblobby - There are multiple verified draught scripts for all three of the Matrix films knocking around. The "Gregory edit" for Matrix Reloaded is a particularly interesting, since the makers went in a completely different direction for the sequels and totally erased an entire major new character in favour of keeping largely the same original cast.

@Valorum - ok, interesting. Have to say I lost interest in the movies after the first one. Took me a long time to get round to watching the sequels, by then I didn't have much interest left. Thanks, I'll have a read around...

I'm not sure I recall anything extremely official that directly acknowledges the veracity of the April 8 1996 script, but I do recall at least one canonical source that lines up with how that script frames an important scene.
I'm not certain if it is the earliest source acknowledging this, but in "The Art of the Matrix" (production started in mid 99 and published in 2000), the first section titled "Your Men Are Already Dead." (pages 9-46) includes original storyboards and commentary by Steve Skroce. Starting around page 30, the storyboards and commentary all acknowledge that, as written, part of the sequence includes the El Train in Chicago (and explains that this was changed when shooting was moved to Sydney).
The April 8 1996 script does include the El Train portion of this sequence.
Someone could have fabricated this part of the script if they knew this information, of course. If any sources of the April 8 1996 script (or at least sources discussing it) predate "The Art of The Matrix" or any other publicly-released source acknowledging the El Train sequence, we could at least conclude that the set of people with the knowledge needed to fabricate that section would have been pretty small.

I also have the 1997 version in my library. Both were originally posted from non-dubious sources like Scriptshadow
